# Using GSON to transform a nested JSON Stream

Tags: java, json, gson

**Purpose**: Using GSON take an input stream of a large JSON file and expose it downstream functions as an Iterator; with the added constraint that I physically can't store the entire JSON File in memory.  Currently I do have this working using some basic Java code that does the following:

- knows when to skip curly braces
- read the stream until it finds the next valid JSON Object
- parse that into a POJO using GSON

**Desired Outcome** See if GSON has the built in ability to replace my custom Java code.

**SAMPLE INPUT DOCUMENT**

```
{
    "header":
    {
        "header1":"value1",
        "header2":"value2",
        "header3":"value3"
    },
    "body":
    {
        "obj-1":
        {
            "id":"obj-1",
            "name":"obj-1-name",
            "description":"obj-1-description"
        },
        "obj-2":
        {
            "id":"obj-2",
            "name":"obj-2-name",
            "description":"obj-2-description"
        },
        "obj-3":
        {
            "id":"obj-3",
            "name":"obj-3-name",
            "description":"obj-3-description"
        },
        "obj-4":
        {
            "id":"obj-4",
            "name":"obj-4-name",
            "description":"obj-4-description"
        }
    }
}
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT DOCUMENT**

```
{
    "header":
    {
        "header1":"value1",
        "header2":"value2",
        "header3":"value3"
    },  
    "object":
    {
        "id":"obj-1",
        "name":"obj-1-name",
        "description":"obj-1-description"
    }
}
```

POJO's have been created for the "header" object, the individual elements in the "body" JSON Object, and the output document.

Using the following as a stepping stone to initially solve the problem, https://howtodoinjava.com/gson/jsonreader-streaming-json-parser/, is it my understanding that since there is an transformation of the JSON Structure I would need to do that basic 3 step process; just translate it into GSON specific functions?

Comment: Should every entry in `body` be wrapped into a new JSON object which duplicates the `header`? For example, would your "Sample output document" look the same for `obj-2`? Just to be sure that there is no misunderstanding, you want to convert `InputDocument` → `Iterator<OutputDocument>`, right?

Comment: Yes.  For each element the header object does not change.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the linked tutorial, you should use [`JsonReader`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html) when you want to process JSON data in a streaming way. You can then use the respective [`TypeAdapter`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) instances obtained from Gson for your POJO classes and use them to parse the header and the individual body objects.
You could also use the `Gson.fromJson(JsonReader, ...)` method instead of directly using the `TypeAdapter` instances; however Gson unfortunately does not respect the leniency setting / always [makes the reader lenient](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html#setLenient(boolean)). Unless you explicitly need this, I would recommend against this and instead directly use the `TypeAdapter` instances because then the leniency setting of the `JsonReader` is respected.

Assuming you have the following POJO classes:

```java
public class Header {
  public String header1;
  public String header2;
  public String header3;
}

public class BodyObject {
  public String id;
  public String name;
  public String description;
}

public class OutputDocument {
  public Header header;
  public BodyObject object;
}
```

Then you could create a method which creates a `Stream<OutputDocument>` like the following. Using a [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) here has the advantage that it's `close` method can be used to close the `Reader` providing the JSON data. However it can also be implemented in a similar way using an `Iterator`.

```java
/**
 * Creates a {@link Stream} which transforms the data to {@link OutputDocument} elements.
 * 
 * <p><b>Important:</b> The provided reader will be closed by this method, or by the created
 * stream. It is therefore necessary to call {@link Stream#close()} (for example by using a
 * try-with-resources statement).
 * 
 * @param inputDocumentReader JSON data stream
 * @param gson Gson object used for looking up adapters
 * @return Stream of transformed elements
 */
public static Stream<OutputDocument> transform(Reader inputDocumentReader, Gson gson) throws IOException {
  JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(inputDocumentReader);
  try {
    jsonReader.beginObject();
    String headerProperty = jsonReader.nextName();
    if (!headerProperty.equals("header")) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected 'header' property at " + jsonReader.getPath());
    }

    // Read the Header
    TypeAdapter<Header> headerAdapter = gson.getAdapter(Header.class);
    Header header = headerAdapter.read(jsonReader);


    String bodyProperty = jsonReader.nextName();
    if (!bodyProperty.equals("body")) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected 'body' property at " + jsonReader.getPath());
    }

    // Start reading body
    jsonReader.beginObject();
    TypeAdapter<BodyObject> bodyObjectAdapter = gson.getAdapter(BodyObject.class);

    long estimatedSize = Long.MAX_VALUE; // unknown size
    // Could also add `| NONNULL`, if there are no null body objects
    int characteristics = Spliterator.Spliterator.ORDERED;
    Spliterator<OutputDocument> spliterator = new AbstractSpliterator<>(estimatedSize, characteristics) {
      @Override
      public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super OutputDocument> action) {
        try {
          // Check if end of 'body' object has been reached
          if (!jsonReader.hasNext()) {
            // End 'body'
            jsonReader.endObject();
            // End top level object
            jsonReader.endObject();

            if (jsonReader.peek() != JsonToken.END_DOCUMENT) {
              throw new IllegalStateException("Expected end of JSON document at " + jsonReader.getPath());
            }
            // Reached end
            return false;
          } else {
            // Skip entry name
            jsonReader.skipValue();

            BodyObject object = bodyObjectAdapter.read(jsonReader);

            // Create combined OutputDocument
            OutputDocument result = new OutputDocument();
            result.header = header;
            result.object = object;

            action.accept(result);
            return true;
          }
        } catch (IOException e) {
          throw new UncheckedIOException("Failed reading next element", e);
        }
      }
    };
    return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, false) // false, don't create parallel stream
        .onClose(() -> {
          try {
            jsonReader.close();
          } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException("Failed closing JsonReader", e);
          }
        });
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    try {
      jsonReader.close();
    } catch (IOException suppressed) {
      e.addSuppressed(suppressed);
    }
    throw e;
  }
}
```

This method can then be called like this:

```java
try (Stream<OutputDocument> stream = transform(inputDocumentReader, new Gson())) {
    ...
}
```

`inputDocumentReader` is the `Reader` you created for your InputDocument file. The `Gson` instance can either be a new instance (as shown in the example above), or it can be one which you have created with [`GsonBuilder`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html) in case you registered custom adapters to customize how the POJO classes or their fields are deserialized.